# Is there a way to mathematically describe "surprise"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, intuition, random, information-theory

Let's say that there are ten people entered into a random drawing, the winner gets some large prize.

If I were one of those ten people, and I were to win, then I would be pleasantly surprised.  If some other person were to win, then that person (from their own perspective) would be equally surprised.

Here's where my thoughts get a little fuzzy:

From the perspective of an outside observer (not involved in the random drawing), both of the above outcomes appear equivalent.  The fact that *somebody* won the drawing is not very surprising at all.

Is there any way to measure the true amount of "surprise" in a given situation, in a way that can be agreed upon by everyone?

Comment: Possibly related: [Surprisal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-information). Possibly also related: [Unexpected hanging paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_hanging_paradox)

Answer (score 1):

The name for the concept you're describing is "informational entropy". Wikipedia has a good article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29